# Pregunta al crear comment en rails + graphql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

estoy haciendo una aplicacion con rails y servicios de graphql al momento de crear un comentario me aparece el siguiente error.

> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "Validation failed: User must exist, Post must exist",

Al momento de crear el comentario, busco el post id y el body que pasa a traves de argumentos.  mi consulta se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
mutation {
 createComment(input: {
  postId: 6,
  body: "post del usuario 5"
  }) {
  id
 }
}
```

mi consulta al servicio de hace de la siguiente forma:

```
class Mutations::CreateComment <   Mutations::BaseMutation
     argument :post_id, ID, required: true
     argument :body, String, required: true

type Types::CommentType

def resolve(body: nil, post_id: nil)
    user = context[:current_user]

    post_id = Post.find(post_id)

    comment = Comment.create!(
        post_id: post_id,
        body: body
    )  

    return { comment: comment }
end
end
```

el modelo de comment:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :post
end
```

y para post:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listo el error estaba en que no buscaba al post_id para agregarle el comentario. Ademas me mostraba un error con respecto a un usuario que no estaba registrado.

```
class Mutations::CreateComment <   Mutations::BaseMutation
 argument :post_id, ID, required: true
 argument :body, String, required: true

type Types::CommentType

def resolve(body: nil, post_id: nil)
user = context[:current_user]

post_id = Post.find(post_id)

comment = post_id.comment.create!(
    body: body
)  

return { comment: comment }
end
end
```